# how to remove validation message created by validator when reseting form in laravel octobercms

Tags: laravel, validation

form validation:

**Component**

```
public function onContact()
    {
        $input = post();
        //$contact = Contact::create($input);

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|alpha',
            'designation' => 'required',
            'note' => 'required',
            'contactNo' => 'required|numeric|max:10',
            'emailIdText' => 'required|email',
            'companyName' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        } else {


            $contact = new Contact;
            $contact->name = $input['name'];
            $contact->designation = $input['designation'];
            $contact->note = $input['note'];
            $contact->inquiry_about = $input['option'];
            $contact->email_id = $input['emailIdText'];
            $contact->contact_no = $input['contactNo'];
            $contact->company_name = $input['companyName'];
            $contact->save();
}
}
```

default.htm

```
 <form id="myform" autocomplete="off" action="{{ 'contactUs'|page }} "
          data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onContact"  data-request-validate data-request-flash
          method="post" name="myform" class="contact-form">
        <table height="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" class="contactUs">
            <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td class="Fieldname" >Inquiry About : </td>
                <td valign="top" >
                    <select class="comboFieldontact" name="option" id="option" >

                        <option value="Existing Client" selected>Existing Client</option>

                        <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>

                        <option value="Media">Media</option>

                        <option value="Investor">Investor</option>

                        <option value="Association">Association</option>

                        <option value="Career">Career</option>

                    </select>
                    <span class="Error"  data-validate-for="inquiry_about" id="optionTextError" ></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Name :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="textFieldContact">
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="name" id="nameTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Email : </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="contactemailIdText" name="emailIdText" class="textFieldContact" >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="emailIdText" id="contactemailIdTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Contact No :
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="15" id="contactNo" name="contactNo" class="textFieldContact"
                           >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="contactNo" id="contactNoTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Company Name :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="companyName" name="companyName" class="textFieldContact"
                          >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="companyName" id="companyNameTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Designation :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="designation" name="designation" class="textFieldContact" >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="designation" id="designationTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Fieldname"> Note :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <textarea class="textarea" name="note" id="note" style="color: #000;" ></textarea>

                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="note" id="fromTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="Fieldname"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" class="contactBtn" value="Submit" >
                    <input type="reset" id="resetbtn" class="contactBtn" value="Reset">

                </td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

form validation is perfectly fine but i want to reset form along with validation error message how can i do this?

when clicking to reset button input in input fields resets but error msgs are still shown......................................................
what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, use this JavaScript code to clear out all of your  tags that have an error class.

```
<script>
function clearErrors() {
 var form = document.getElementById('myform').querySelectorAll('span.Error');
    for (i=0; i<=form.length; i++) {
        form[i].innerText = '';
    }
}
</script>

 <form id="myform" autocomplete="off" action="{{ 'contactUs'|page }} "
          data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onContact"  data-request-validate data-request-flash
          method="post" name="myform" class="contact-form">
        <table height="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" class="contactUs">
            <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td class="Fieldname" >Inquiry About : </td>
                <td valign="top" >
                    <select class="comboFieldontact" name="option" id="option" >

                        <option value="Existing Client" selected>Existing Client</option>

                        <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>

                        <option value="Media">Media</option>

                        <option value="Investor">Investor</option>

                        <option value="Association">Association</option>

                        <option value="Career">Career</option>

                    </select>
                    <span class="Error"  data-validate-for="inquiry_about" id="optionTextError" ></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Name :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="textFieldContact">
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="name" id="nameTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Email : </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="contactemailIdText" name="emailIdText" class="textFieldContact" >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="emailIdText" id="contactemailIdTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Contact No :
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="15" id="contactNo" name="contactNo" class="textFieldContact"
                           >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="contactNo" id="contactNoTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Company Name :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="companyName" name="companyName" class="textFieldContact"
                          >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="companyName" id="companyNameTextError" ></span></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="Fieldname">Designation :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="text" id="designation" name="designation" class="textFieldContact" >
                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="designation" id="designationTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Fieldname"> Note :</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <textarea class="textarea" name="note" id="note" style="color: #000;" ></textarea>

                    <span class="Error" data-validate-for="note" id="fromTextError" ></span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="Fieldname"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" class="contactBtn" value="Submit" >
                    <button type="reset" onclick="clearErrors()">Reset</button>

                </td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thankyou just save me

Comment: @kajalsingh You're welcome, would you Kindly accept this as the answer?

Comment: do you how to send json data from frontend and show them in repeater control at backend in octoberCMS

Comment: @kajalsingh Do they have an API?

Comment: naah ,i use save() please just look in component's coding

Comment: @KristlyD'sena Can you provide me some documentation?

Comment: mmmm documentation about what?

Comment: @KristlyD'sena About octoberCMS. I have never heard of it.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/api/backend/formwidgets/repeater and actually i solved it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to hide the elements with the class 'error' with jQuery by clicking on the reset button ?

Another method is to change the reset button with an empty href. By clicking on the button it will refresh the page and the form I guess.